# SQL: Get single result id from multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have two table which looks like this:

```
conversations

conversation_id | type    | updated_at
     50         | private | 2018-01-01 15:50:51
     30         | group   | 2019-01-01 15:50:49
    100         | private | 2018-01-01 15:50:55
```

and

```
conversation_participants

user_id | conversation_id
1       | 100
3       | 50
5       | 99
6       | 50
6       | 30
3       | 30
2       | 30
```

How can I now select the `conversation_id` depending on two `user_id` and the type of the conversation?

For example, give me the `conversation_id` from user 3 and 6 which is private. So i would get `conversation_id` 50.

My approach so far:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM conversation_participants as cp 
    LEFT JOIN conversations as c 
       ON c.conversation_id = cp.conversation_id
 WHERE c.type = 'private'
```

But how can I fetch the `conversation_id` depending on different rows?

Comment: Note that `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x=...` is a contradiction in terms. In the example above, and depending on what you actually want, either change `LEFT JOIN` to `[INNER] JOIN`, or change `WHERE` to `AND`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to know which converstion are private

```
SELECT conversation_id 
FROM conversations c
WHERE c.type = 'private'
```

Then you need to see what conversation have users 3 and 6 using a SELF JOIN

```
SELECT conversation_id
FROM conversation_participants cp1
JOIN conversation_participants cp2
  ON cp1.conversation_id = cp2.conversation_id
WHERE cp1 = 3
  AND cp2 = 6
```

Now you filter only the private conversations

```
SELECT conversation_id
FROM conversation_participants cp1
JOIN conversation_participants cp2
  ON cp1.conversation_id = cp2.conversation_id
WHERE conversation_id IN (  SELECT conversation_id 
                            FROM conversations c
                            WHERE c.type = 'private' )
 AND cp1 = 3
 AND cp2 = 6
```

You can also use a third join

```
SELECT conversation_id
FROM conversation_participants cp1
JOIN conversation_participants cp2
  ON cp1.conversation_id = cp2.conversation_id
JOIN conversations c
  ON cp1.conversation_id = c.conversation_id   
WHERE c.type = 'private' 
 AND cp1 = 3
 AND cp2 = 6
```

Comment: Probably the 3 join is the better way if you have setup the proper index. I leave the other solution as teaching the process to find the right result

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you start by selecting conversations based on your participants. For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM conversation_participants cp
WHERE cp.user_id IN (3, 6)
```

To also include only private conversations, you'll have to join `conversation_participants` to `conversations`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM conversation_participants cp
    INNER JOIN conversations c ON
        c.conversation_id = cp.conversation_id
WHERE
    cp.user_id IN (3, 6)
    AND c.type = 'private'
```

Of course, this query will include a row for each user in the conversation. If you want to only have 1 row, you can group by conversation. Something like this:

```
SELECT
    c.conversation_id,
    c.updated_at,
    COUNT(*) AS participant_count
FROM conversation_participants cp
    INNER JOIN conversations c ON
        c.conversation_id = cp.conversation_id
WHERE
    cp.user_id IN (3, 6)
    AND c.type = 'private'
 GROUP BY 
    c.conversation_id,
    c.updated_at
```

You'll need to use the `GROUPING` clause, and also add a `HAVING` clause, to refine your query (especially if you want to search for a conversation specifying more than 2 participants):

```
SELECT
    c.conversation_id,
    COUNT(*) AS participant_count
FROM conversations c
    INNER JOIN conversation_participants cp ON
        cp.conversation_id = c.conversation_id
WHERE
    c.type = 'private'
    AND cp.user_id IN (3, 6)
 GROUP BY c.conversation_id
 HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: I assume op want 3 and 6 be on the same conversation. but your solution works if that isnt a requirement

Comment: @Juan: I was also thinking of conversations with 3+ people---self-joins are going to be harder to maintain that way than simply using an `IN` clause.

Comment: Again, `IN` doesnt guarantee 3 and 6 are on the same conversation. Just say they are IN a conversation. So wont work for 3 people conversation either

Comment: You can add a `HAVING` clause to make sure all your specified participants are in the same conversation. I'll update my answer to reflect that.